# Bootstrap - custom radio buttons

Tags: bootstrap-4

I would like to make some custom bootstrap radio buttons.
I saw the documentation: https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/components/buttons/#checkbox-and-radio-buttons

Is their a way to separate the buttons so they look like 3 separated buttons and not like one long button.

And if their is such way - can I change the colour of the chosen button when the user chooses it?

Thank you!

Answer (score -1, accepted):

```html
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no">
  <title>Bootstrap</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.3/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-MCw98/SFnGE8fJT3GXwEOngsV7Zt27NXFoaoApmYm81iuXoPkFOJwJ8ERdknLPMO" crossorigin="anonymous">
</head>

<body>
  <div class="btn-group btn-group-toggle" data-toggle="buttons">
    <label class="btn btn-primary rounded mr-1 active">
   <input type="radio" name="options" id="option1" autocomplete="off" checked=""> Active
  </label>
    <label class="btn btn-success rounded mr-1">
   <input type="radio" name="options" id="option2" autocomplete="off"> Radio
  </label>
    <label class="btn btn-danger rounded">
   <input type="radio" name="options" id="option3" autocomplete="off"> Radio
  </label>
  </div>
  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-q8i/X+965DzO0rT7abK41JStQIAqVgRVzpbzo5smXKp4YfRvH+8abtTE1Pi6jizo" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.14.3/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-ZMP7rVo3mIykV+2+9J3UJ46jBk0WLaUAdn689aCwoqbBJiSnjAK/l8WvCWPIPm49" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
  <script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.3/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-ChfqqxuZUCnJSK3+MXmPNIyE6ZbWh2IMqE241rYiqJxyMiZ6OW/JmZQ5stwEULTy" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
</body>

</html>
```

If you ever heard about "margins", yes you can.

Answer (score -1):

*You're basically asking how to use a component for something that hasn't been built for.

It is advisable to use radio buttons as radio buttons and normal buttons as normal buttons.*

**Anyway, this is how you can do it (one of the many ways):**
add the class `mr-1` to each button. It will add some `margin-right` that you can customise in your `_variables.scss` file, by adding this class your buttons will be separated by some space.